# invalid syntax while printing multiline code with a single print command in python

Tags: python, syntax-error

When I executed below code, the interpreter gives me a SyntaxError. How can I fix it?

```py
print("Day 1 - String Manipulation\nString Concatenation is done with the "+" sign.\n e.g. print("Hello " + "world")\nNew lines can be created with a backslash and n.")
```

Comment: If my answer below, doesnot satisfy your answer, then could you please elaborate your question

Comment: How are you imagining that Python is going to be able to distinguish between the quote marks that delimit your string, and the quote marks that you want to appear in the string?  You either have to escape the quotes in the string with a preceding backslash, or choose a different form of quoting to delimit the string (your other choices are `'`, `"""`, and `'''`).

Answer (score 0):

there are various ways that you can utilize the print statement. Some of them are listed bewlow.

**print**("Hello " + "\nworld")   # concatination. Note: the data types

**print**(f"Hello \nWorld. {some_othervariables}")   # f-string way

**print**("Hello \n" , "world")

Comment: i want them to print all with one print statement. the answer should like.                   
Day 1 - String Manipulation
String Concatenation is done with the "+" sign.
e.g. print("Hello " + "world")
New lines can be created with a backslash and n.